# Fill Python DataFrame Values that are not 0s with 1s

Tags: python, dataframe, fill

I would like to know if there is a way to fill python DataFrame values that are not 0s with 1s. I would like to do it without a for loop. In the picture you cann see what the DataFrame looks like

Thanks!!!

[DataFrame Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mf6e.png)

Comment: Please don't post images. Share it as code. Also provide a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe:

```py
df=df.ne(0).astype(int)
```